# Font switch in ConTeXt mkiv

Tags: fonts, fontsize, context-mkiv, modules

I am struggling to switch the fonts in ConTeXt accordingly and feel that I am missing something basic. I try to mimic

```
\RequirePackage{fontspec}

% Use Neo Euler as math font
\RequirePackage[vargreek-shape=TeX]{unicode-math}% 
\setmathfont{Asana Math}%
% Use the Palatino-Clone Tex Gyre Pagella as main font
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Numbers=OldStyle]{Tex Gyre Pagella}%
% Use Tex Gyre Cursor as Monospace Font
\setmonofont{Tex Gyre Cursor}%
% Use Tex Gyre Heros Cn as Sans Serif Font
\setsansfont{Tex Gyre Heros}%
% fontsize is 10pt, 13pt for book and 12pt, 15pt for handout
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{10pt}{13pt}\selectfont}%
% fontsize is 10pt, 13pt for book and 9pt, 11pt for kindle
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\selectfont}%
```

which works fine in a LuaLaTeX file.

My best try so far is

```
%setup the fonts
\usemodule[simplefonts] 
\definefontfeature[default][default][onum=yes]
%
\setmathfont[Asana Math]%
% Use the Palatino-Clone Tex Gyre Pagella as main font
\setmainfont[Tex Gyre Pagella]%
% Use Tex Gyre Cursor as Monospace Font
\setmonofont[Tex Gyre Cursor]%
% Use Tex Gyre Heros Cn as Sans Serif Font
\setsansfont[Tex Gyre Heros]%
\setupbodyfont[TeX Gyre Pagella,10pt]

\definebodyfontenvironment [10pt] [a=16pt]

\starttext
italic but not math \it mathmode 123

$123 mathmode$

\tfa Big
\stoptext
```

I know that a couple of things go wrong here. My question is now: What is best practice in context? I feel that I am mixing `simplefonts` macros (`setmainfont`) with `context-core` ones (`\setupbodyfont[TeX Gyre Pagella,10pt]`).

Could someone clarify if I have to use different `simplefonts` macros for e.g. fontsize? Do I have to decide, either only `context-core` or `simplefonts`. And which one is recommended?

Comment: Is there a preferred way? I guess without module is recommended?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simplefonts based solution:

```
\definefontfeature[default][default][onum=yes]
\usemodule[simplefonts][size=10pt]

\setmathfont[Asana]
\setmainfont[Tex Gyre Pagella]
\setmonofont[Tex Gyre Cursor]
\setsansfont[Tex Gyre Heros]

\definebodyfontenvironment [10pt] [a=16pt]

\starttext
italic but not math {\it mathmode 123}

$123 mathmode$

\tfa Big

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 12):

Typescript-based version :

```
\usetypescriptfile[asana]

\definefontfeature[default][default][onum=yes]

\starttypescript[me]
    \definetypeface [me] [rm] [serif] [pagella] [default]
    \definetypeface [me] [ss] [sans]  [heros]   [default]
    \definetypeface [me] [tt] [mono]  [cursor]  [default]
    \definetypeface [me] [mm] [math]  [asana]   [default]
\stoptypescript

\definebodyfontenvironment [10pt] [a=16pt]

\setupbodyfont[me,10pt]

\starttext
italic but not math \it mathmode 123

$123 mathmode$

\tfa Big
\stoptext
```

Comment: Either you do not have the Asana font installed, or your ConTeXt is too old (the first is likelier).

Answer (score 5):

Aditya's solution is great but unfortunately outdated.  ConTeXt is developed at a very fast pace and a lot happened since 2012.  The documentation of the [`simplefonts`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/simplefonts) module lists some changes and I have implemented them on the basis of Aditya's example.

Today you perhaps want to use the official companion math font for TeX Gyre Pagella instead of Asana Math.

```
\definefontfeature[default][default][onum=yes]
\definefontfamily[texgyre][serif][TeX Gyre Pagella]
\definefontfamily[texgyre][sans] [TeX Gyre Heros]
\definefontfamily[texgyre][mono] [TeX Gyre Cursor][features=none]
\definefontfamily[texgyre][math] [TeX Gyre Pagella Math]
\setupbodyfont[texgyre,10pt]

\starttext
italic but not math {\it mathmode 123}

$123 mathmode$

\tfa Big
\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The best practice in my opinion is to use typescripts. The Context-Wiki is always
a great place to look for Context specific stuff. In this case it's [Fonts in Context (LauTeX)](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Fonts_in_LuaTeX).

Comment: What would be the code in the case at hand?

Comment: The given code is derived from that page (section:"With the simplefonts module") and kind of works, but my question goes in a different direction.